# Mbox isn't refreshing the object

Tags: flutter, dart, mbox

I'm making a screen using Mbox, however it aren't refresh my object.

I wanna just show a List of string for after create a table with this information.

My Mbox code is it:

```
abstract class ControllerResearchBase with Store {

Pesquisa _finalResearch = new Pesquisa();

  set finalResearch(Pesquisa pesquisa) {
    _finalResearch = pesquisa;
  }

  @observable
  List<String> informationLC = [];

  @action
  void changeLojaOrConcorrete({int op = 0}) {
    informationLC.clear();
    if (_finalResearch == null) informationLC.add("Error, pesquisa vazia");
    if (op == 0) {
      if (_finalResearch.loja == null) {
        informationLC.add("Error, loja vazia");
        return;
      }
      _finalResearch.loja.forEach((element) {
        informationLC.add(element.desLoja);
      });
    } else if (op == 1) {
      if (_finalResearch.concorrente == null) {
        informationLC.add("Error, concorrente vazia");
        return;
      }
      _finalResearch.concorrente.forEach((element) {
        informationLC.add(element.desConco);
      });
    } else {
      informationLC.add("Opção invalida");
    }
  }
```

I already create the class ControllerResearch and file.g.dart

The simple screen is:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ControllerResearch controller = new ControllerResearch();
    UtilsWidgetsComponents _components = new UtilsWidgetsComponents();
    controller.finalResearch = finalResearch;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: _components.colorAppBar(),
          title: Center(child: Text('Detalhes')),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.changeLojaOrConcorrete(op: 0);
                      },
                      child: Text("Lojas")),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.changeLojaOrConcorrete(op: 1);
                      },
                      child: Text("Concorrentes")),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Observer(builder: (_) => Text("${controller.informationLC}"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
   );
}
```

In my prints debug, the information is correct, However at screen is showing []

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem could be that you are restarting your controller every time build is called:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ControllerResearch controller = new ControllerResearch();
   UtilsWidgetsComponents _components = new UtilsWidgetsComponents();
   controller.finalResearch = finalResearch;
```

If you move your variables to outside of build method, it could fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I put at post only a part of code, I'm referencing the Mbox with a Controller, I going to update the post.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm using a statelessWidget, not a statefullWidget for not restarting the controller every time build is called

Comment: So this couldn't be the problem? StatelessWidgets are designed to not update, to not be dynamic. Because that, build is called once.

Comment: Yes, however I'm using Mobx on StatelessWidget becase I wanna reload only a part in my screen, if I use a StatefullWidget, all the my screen will be reload.

Comment: Okay, but the Mobx needs to be into the part of screen that will be rebuild (a Stateful Widget). Otherwise, it will not work. What you could do is move the part of screen that you dont want to reload to another file, a StatelessWidget, and call it on your page. Do you understand what i'm saying?

Comment: Right, I understood, I going try it.

Comment: I change the code although still it isn't work,  so I analyze my code and when I change "informationLC.add("Error, loja vazia");" for "informationLC = (["Error, loja vazia"]);" It's work.

Comment: The problem was at Mbox code, not at screen

Comment: Congrats!!! Just by curiosity, your code works as a StatelessWidget after your change?

Comment: Also, i don't understand why the add method isn't working.

Comment: I also didn't understand, I guess the Mobx @oberservable only notify when the local variable reference change, or like that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Mbox code for:

```
  @action
  Future changeLojaOrConcorrete({int op = 0}) async {
    //-1 == invalid
    //0 == loja
    //1 == concorrente
    List<String> saida = [];
    informationLC = [];
    if (_finalResearch == null) saida.add("Error, pesquisa vazia");
    if (op == 0) {
      if (_finalResearch.loja == null) {
        saida.add("Error, loja vazia");
      }

      _finalResearch.loja.forEach((element) {
        saida.add(element.desLoja);
      });
    } else if (op == 1) {
      if (_finalResearch.concorrente == null) {
        saida.add("Error, concorrente vazia");
      }
      _finalResearch.concorrente.forEach((element) {
        saida.add(element.desConco);
      });
    } else {
      saida.add("Opção invalida");
    }
    informationLC = saida;
  }
```

When I changed information.add('something') for information = ['something'], it worked. Apparently, Mobx @oberservable don't work very well with methods List<>, or like that.